# Setting v-model with q-carousel using v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a quasar carousel within a v-for loop, which works, but the issue is that **the slide does not start with the first image, it's blank**. The first image is blank, then when rotated, the first image comes into view.

I'm positive that the issue is that the slide is starting as an indeterminate state, but I cannot figure out how to set v-model to the first value of the slide with the v-for loop.

Note: the locations array contains locImgPaths, locNumb, locName values. The locImgPaths is an array of all img urls I want to display for the particular location.

I'm trying to create a codepen, but it isn't going well: https://codepen.io/kiggs1881/pen/gOXXNqG

```
<template>
   <div v-for="(loc, i) in locations" :key="i">
      <q-carousel
        v-model="slides[i]" <--this needs to be the name of the first 
slide
        arrows
        infinite
    
      >
        <q-carousel-slide
          v-for="(img, id) in loc.imgUrls"
          :key="id"
          :name="id"
          :img-src="img.url"
        />
      </q-carousel>
    </div>
     </template>
 <script>
   export default {
   setup() {
     let locations = ref([]);
     let slides = ref({});
     
     return {
       locations,
       slides,
    };
   },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: hard to tell, `locations` is not defined

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

v-model="slides[i]"

to

v-model="images[i].imgPaths[i].url"

and assigned the key and name of the slides to "img.url"